# Can we generate a WSDL from an Apex class

Tags: class

Is it possible to generate WSDL from an Apex class ??

Cause i want to check one request but i don't have the WSDl to check from SOAP UI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you have marked your method as webservice , then you can use the Generate WSDL option to get the wsdl for the APEX webservice

**reference :**
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_web_services_methods.htm

Comment: any idea if this class is referring to other classes and so on, will it include all such classes??